# Adding a self-signed cert to the trusted certs within cURL in Windows?

Tags: php, ssl, ssl-certificate, curl

I have created a self-signed cert from the instructions on [this page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self), have installed it and it appears to all be working correctly, but now I need `cURL` to trust it.

Since the later versions of cURL don't include a trusted list within a `.pem` file, I downloaded the .pem file [here](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) and then input this line in `php.ini`:

```
curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem"
```

Now all I need to know is how do I get `cURL` to trust my self-signed cert? I don't need any browsers to trust it, just cURL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems all I had to do was open up the `cacert.pem` file and add the contents of the `server.crt` file to it.

For those reading, `server.crt` was the file that got created when I created the self-signed cert and which I copied over to: `C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.crt\server.crt`

Comment: Hi, I tried with above suggested solution and many more options with other blogs, but I am still facing same issue. Kindly suggest

Comment: @HirenSoni I would create a new question with your issue and your code so it is easier to narrow down your issue. When doing your `cURL` call you may need to include the path like so.. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'curl_path_here';`

Comment: thank you for quick response. Actually the issue is, I am using composer to download package and that repo is protected with SSL. So the issue occurred while downloading package with composer.

Comment: @HirenSoni In that case it shouldn't have anything to do with using a self-signed SSL cert on your local machine? Sounds like you need the protocol you are using to connect to the repo to trust the SSL cert they are using; probably a bit outside the scope of this question and better to create a new one?

Comment: Thank you for update, I will try and update in case if I found any solution.

Comment: The error message I was getting was: "curl error (#60): ssl certificate problem: self signed certificate". It took a fair amount of searching before finding this post which fixed my problem. I'm hoping that adding the error message will help others to find the solution quicker. My config: Windows 10, Apache 2.4,  PHP 8.1 with Apache's virtual host pointing to self-signed server.crt